# Why does axios.get a side effect and axios.post not one?

Tags: reactjs

I'm following a react tutorial about todo-list with jsonplaceholder. In it we need to make a get request to https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos, and we have this code:

```
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  useEffect(
   () => {
    Axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_limit=10')
    .then(({data}) => {
      setTodos(data);
    });
  }, []);
```

According to what I read, effects mean that function changes something outside of its scope, and not just return a value, and also with the same parameters it can give different results. At least that's how I understand about side-effects. But how does it apply in the context of this get? Does axios.get change anything, or does it return different value with different calls? I know that making a request to a third party is always an effect, but how does that work? At the same time I have addTodo function:

```
  const addTodo = (title) => {
    Axios.post("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos", {
      title: title,
      completed: false
    }).then(({data}) => setTodos([...todos, data]));
  }
```

Why does this not need useEffect hook. It seems like addTodo changes the value of todos state, does it not? Why is there not useEffect() this time. Thanks for reading and my apology if there are a little bit too many questions. I don't think they need to be asked seperately.

Comment: the `useEffect` here is to ensure that the todos are loaded when the component is mounted (component mounting is an effect). The `addTodo` method is (presumably) an action handler and not an effect

Comment: it has nothing to do with axios

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with axios and everything to do with when you want to execute your code. Just to clarify, axios doesn't *need* `useEffect` to work at all.

`useEffect` is a hook that allows you to perform actions *after* your component has mounted. It makes sense to place code in here that you perhaps only need to run once e.g. loading some data, hooking up event handlers, update the DOM etc. In your example, you load your list of Todos here, which makes sense as you probably only need to do this one time.

For code that *doesn't* need to run right away, like your `addTodo`, then you can trigger this as and when e.g. on a button click, timer, whatever makes sense for your application.

*Note - `useEffect` can be triggered more than once using [dependencies](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) but it's not important for this example*

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. Does this mean that useEffect is only used to tell the browser to mount the todos gotten from the get request after everything is rendered, and not relating to side-effects like I talked about? You know, the one where it changed something outside its scope...?

Comment: @GoldExperience the clue is in the name, it is for performing side-effects, it's just not the _only_ way you can run side-effects. A side-effect isn't a React term, it's a [programming concept](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science))

Comment: Can you show me what is considered a side effect in my example? If I understand correctly, the anonymous function inside useEffect is a side effect, right? But of what exactly? Thank you again.

Comment: @FreeMe an axios request is a side effect in the sense that it has nothing to do with generating the current render, it has to do with obtaining some data to be used at a later time.